# Work-in-progress post for our community ad ideas

Tags: discussion

In this meta post we throw around any wild ideas for our community ads which would be displayed on other sites, should they reach the score of 6 points, and before that some approval from our own users. Post your text-only ideas in [this answer below](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2602), and work-in-progress images in the corresponding answers. Don't be shy to propose other fonts, images, background, etc if you think it will improve the ad!

Comment: Since [japanese.se] just graduated, they have a community-ads post now (http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1421/). It would be nice to get a post up there - we currently have few Japanese users, but when we do get them to come over here, they generally have very good answers. I can suggest some Japanese-language copy if someone wants to turn it into a reasonable-looking ad.

Comment: Previous versions of this post: [Feb 2013](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/364/), [Dec 2013](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/761/).

Answer (score 6):

## Protagonist near window

[Why are the protagonists generally seated by the window?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/why-are-the-protagonists-generally-seated-by-the-window)

[image]

Comment: What other site could this possibly be relevant on?

Comment: I wasn't aware they are supposed to be partially relevant to any other site

Comment: Well, I mean, it doesn't _have_ to be, but it does have to garner a net score of 6 or more from voters on the site, which probably isn't going to happen unless the ad is relevant to users of the site.

Comment: We could just go over and upvote it to 6 >.> it's not like a lot of people vote on those anyways

Answer (score 3):

## Araragi/Monogatari

[image: 1] [image: 2]

Comment: we could have the googley eyed hat too

Answer (score 2):

Something that could go on SF&F since they have loads of Harry Potter questions. Again, feedback is very welcome, photoshop isn't my forté.

[image: The Irregular at Magic High School on Anime & Manga Stack Exchange]

I've currently (unashamedly) linked to my question on ["How does modern magic work"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23635/what-actually-is-modern-magic-and-how-does-it-work), but we can by all means instead just link to the list of questions tagged [mahouka-koukou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahouka-koukou), or even something else if needs be.

Answer (score 1):

## Text-only ideas list

- Ad for our list of recommendations meta post
- Araragi's hair and/or something else that immediately makes you think of Monogatari series
- Kyubei's signature line: "Make a contract with me and become a Magical Girl".
- "Get noticed by senpai / Join Anime & Manga @ Stack Exchange" − [from chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27890935)

Answer (score 1):

> Follow our ID Request guidelines or she'll follow [you.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27896084)

[image]

<sub>[(bonus)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXS1g.gif)</sub>